# Why my vscode always show building when I run extension?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code

https://code.visualstudio.com/api/get-started/your-first-extension

I create a hello world from tutorial.
Why my vscode always show building when I run extension.

> Executing task: npm run watch <
> helloworld@0.0.1 watch D:\work\Plugin\helloworld
> tsc -watch -p ./
> [11:28:42 ├F10: AM┤] Found 0 errors. Watching for file changes.

No error message.

Answer (score -2):

i encounted the same problem just now,
i found the distinction between my project and offical tutorial that is the `webpack` property

#### resolve

- remove your proejct file
- follow the offical tutorial again(each step each parameter)
- and then debugging, it's will run perfectly

#### sample

```
? What type of extension do you want to create? New Extension (TypeScript)
? What's the name of your extension? vsce-window-title
? What's the identifier of your extension? y
? What's the description of your extension? y
? Initialize a git repository? Yes
? Bundle the source code with webpack? No
? Which package manager to use? yarn
```